# python selenium edge webdriver version not supported

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, version, microsoft-edge

I am just getting started with Selenium. Right now I'm using Python. I tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Edge()
```

and got the error message:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687
```

So I followed the link and downloaded the latest version, but got a new error:

```
driver = webdriver.Edge('edgedriver_win64\msedgedriver.exe')

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of MSEdgeDriver only supports MSEdge version 90
Current browser version is 81.0.416.77 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe
```

Now I don't know what to do. The earlies version for the webdrvier found from the [download link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/) is 88.

Comment: Either upgrade your msedge or downgrade the edge driver.

Comment: As I've written in the question, I can't find a earlier version from the link. And I can't upgrade my MSEDGE right now for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update edge browser or use a previous version of driver

You can download previous version from:

https://msedgewebdriverstorage.z22.web.core.windows.net/

Click next page till you get the version you want ,